# ado.net entity framework for oracle 12c identity column

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework

Is there any way to tell entity framework that column is identity col and set storegeneratedpattern= identity automatically. Its a bit problem with doing it manually

```
public partial class EDUCATIONGROUPS 
{ 
    public EDUCATIONGROUPS() { this.EDUCATIONGROUP_EDUCATION = new HashSet<EDUCATIONGROUP_EDUCATION>(); } 
    public int EDUCATIONGROUP_ID { get; set; } 
    public string NAME { get; set; } 
    public System.DateTime MODIFIEDTIME { get; set; } 
    public string MODIFIEDBY { get; set; } 
    public virtual ICollection<EDUCATIONGROUP_EDUCATION> EDUCATIONGROUP_EDUCATION { get; set; } 
}
```

Created as database first.

Comment: Are you using code first or database first? Can you show your class/table/entity definition.

Comment: oracle database first.

Comment: public partial class EDUCATIONGROUPS
    {
         public EDUCATIONGROUPS()
        {
            this.EDUCATIONGROUP_EDUCATION = new HashSet<EDUCATIONGROUP_EDUCATION>();
        }    
        public int EDUCATIONGROUP_ID { get; set; }
        public string NAME { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime MODIFIEDTIME { get; set; }
        public string MODIFIEDBY { get; set; }    
        public virtual ICollection<EDUCATIONGROUP_EDUCATION> EDUCATIONGROUP_EDUCATION { get; set; }     
    }

Comment: You've tagged this as Entity Framework. Is that what you are using? Or are you using ADO.NET.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Goto in your Model Browser Select your Entity then select your property which you want to make identity,See properties of this column and change StoreGenerationPattern to Identity.

Comment: Yes, that is what I am doing right now. But I don't want to do this every time if I have to remove all entities and update from database.

Comment: Why you are removing your entities?

Comment: @BenzhiPan, in one of the email exchange with Oracle support, I was told it's not possible for the ORM mapper to remember that information. But often times, you don't need to remove all the tables and add them again. You only need to remove/add the tables that are changed.